# SharedLibrary.dll was not found and mrt100_app.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this issue

Tags: c#, uwp, shared-libraries, win-universal-app, .net-4.8

I am getting this error when I try to run the UWP application exe file. I have tried to install the files manually, I have updated the visual studio, I have also updated the .Net Framework on my machine. I also checked the path where the file lies its there from the beginning but still, I can not run the UWP exe file.
below are the reference links I have tried to fix the issue.

[Installing SharedLibrary](https://www.dll-files.com/sharedlibrary.dll.html#:%7E:text=The%20code%20execution%20cannot%20proceed,dll%20was%20not%20found.&text=dll%20is%20either%20not%20designed,the%20software%20vender%20for%20support.)

[Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/systems-will-not-open-sharedlibrarydll-and/703b2227-9a10-4faf-af4c-f6351717137b)

[download .Net framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472)

[msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc9c34df-66df-4651-b7dc-068527226c03/uwp-where-to-find-sharedlibrarydll-and-pdb?forum=wpdevelop)

Please find below screenshots of the errors

[image: SharedLibrary.dll error]

[image: mrt100_app.dll error]

It's just a basic UWP app which only has a button on the main page.

I hope I get the answer soon. I really need to resolve this.

TIA

Comment: Hello, when you install a UWP application, please open it from the start menu instead of running the exe file directly in the folder. If the same error occurs, please try the following: 1. Update your system to the latest version. 2. Find your version of Visual Studio in **Visual Studio Installer**, click **Modify**, and in the detailed information on the right, check "Universal Windows Platform Development" to check whether you have installed the SDK of the required version of the application.

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT I have tried this thing as well and also tried to locate both the files on the machine. The files are there on the machine but still, it gives me the same error over and over again.

Comment: Hello, have you tried to reinstall Visual Studio and install it in the default path?

Comment: hello, @RichardZhang-MSFT yes I have tried doing that which did not work.

Comment: Any progress on this problem? @RoshniGandhi

Comment: I facing the same situation. Any progress?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve this or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to "Deploy" the app (Build -> Deploy), useful to run it directly on the current machine outside of VS, or you need to publish it (right click on project, Publish -> Create app packages), useful to create a .msixbundle (or equivalent) that you can deploy using Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 (or equivalent).